# pointer as key of boost unordered_map

Tags: pointers, boost, dictionary, key, unordered-map

I am trying to use an object pointer as a key for the boost unordered_map:

```
boost::unordered_map<MyObject*, real> mymap;
```

but when I try to access the value for a given key, it never finds it:

```
boost::unordered_map<MyObject*, real>::const_iterator it = mymap.find(&SomeObject); // it is always equal to mymap.end()
```

If I print the map contents, I can see the keys are in there:

```
key: 0x3739c60, value: 1
key: 0x4541970, value: 0.873346
...
```

If I replace boost::unordered_map with std::map it works OK.

What's the problem?

Comment: Could you post a minimal complete example code that we can try?

Comment: Ok, I did a "minimal complete example" and cannot reproduce it. I also noticed that in my application using a newer boost version I fix the problem paritaly (it works in some places, but not everywhere). Seems like it is a boost specific thing. Will post any updates...

Comment: I have isolated the problem now. It seems to be a bug in boost 1.42 version. I will write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question...
I figured out using a newer version of boost works OK. Seems to be caused by a bug in boost version 1.42.